# Modifying drupal block text

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

I have a new drupal site on which to work. And i see things like that :

```
print render($page['content_top']);
```

I would like to change the content of 'content_top' in the drupal administration, but I'm totally new at drupal and don't find where it is.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much information (what type of content is currently there, what content you want there, or what version of Drupal you are running), but I will go ahead and assume you want to place a new block in that section, and that you are using Drupal 7.

If this is the case, you should select "Structure" from the administrative menu, then click "blocks."

Comment: Hey, Sorry for the lack of information. I have no idea what type of content is in the block. The thing is that a client gave us his site, and we have no contact with the agency who made the website. All I know is that it's using the bloc 'content', and that when I try to edit the bloc in Structure -> Blocs -> Configure, the only things I can change are : Title and settings, but not the content and yes I'm on Drupal 7

Comment: Is the block being generated by the Views module?
If the Views module is installed, check Structure > Views